# 8051/C: Enter blink-mode when button is pressed, exit when pressed again or after 30 seconds

Tags: c, 8051

So I have an LED and a button.

When the button is pressed, the LED should start blinking.
It either stops blinking after 30s or if the button is pressed again.

I have implemented the entering of the blinking state and leaving it after 30s, but I don't know how to leave it at any time with the push of the button.
Any help appreciated!

```
while(1)
{

    if(button is pressed)
    {
         for(i=0, i<60, i++)
         {
           toggleLED();
           wait(500ms);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there: you need to add watching the button in the intervals between blinking the LED:

```
if(button is pressed)
{
     for(i=0, i<60, i++)
     {
       toggleLED();
       wait(500ms);
       if (button is pressed)
       {
           turnLedOff();
           break;
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thought of that. But it doesnt work. I guess when I break out of the loop it goes right back into it again because the button is still pressed?!

Comment: You can tell between it not getting out of the loop vs. it getting into the loop again by waiting for 20 seconds and pressing the button again: if the LED stops blinking in 10 seconds, it did not get out of the loop; if it stops blinking after 30 seconds, it got into the loop again. If the program goes right back into the loop, you can add a short wait (say, 20 ms) before the `break` to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Tried it and appearently the break doesnt work. When I press the button again it doesnt keep blinking for another 30s but just for the remaining time. Strange...

Comment: Beware of "switch bounce" in the button itself. It will often manifest in actual real-life buttons, and will make semi-naive code like this break since what you perceive as a single off-on transition is in fact more like off-on-off-on-off-on-off-on-off-on, with the "flicker" happening very fast, as the contacts within the switch bounce before finally coming to rest.

Comment: @tzippy This means that you pressed and released the button while your program was inside the `wait(500)` call. If you press and hold through the next toggle, you should be able to exit the loop.

Comment: Okay. The bad thing is, that my button is recognized as "pressed" only if it is in active state for 500ms. Do i have to try a completely diferent approach?

Comment: @tzippy Absolutely: I would try reading the button state in a timer interrupt, say, at every 20 ms, and store the current state in a variable.